# ReactJS: properties of object become undefined after onClick call

Tags: reactjs

I've made a simple React app to display a number of image cards with quotes on them. It worked great, but then I refactored my code because I was getting a warning to use setState instead of directly altering the state properties. Then I started getting this error:

```
App.js:111 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageURL' of undefined
```

I guess this means that even if it was working before, I wasn't doing it properly. I suspect my problem is something to do with setState being asynchronous, but I'm having trouble finding a solution. Any light shed on the matter would be much appreciated!

Code below:

UPDATE:

Thanks for your suggestions! I have some updated code here, which is still returning the same error. Below are the up-to-date files as requested:

```
App.js: https://pastebin.com/daBTNKc7
App.css: https://pastebin.com/68xZdLfT
quotesData.json https://pastebin.com/1xD5DS0z
```

UPDATE 2:

I realised that I wasn't initialising this.state.cards in a sensible way, so the array was empty at a point when render() was trying to read it. I changed my constructor to initialise the array with some placeholder data, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        imagesLoaded: false,
        cards: [],
        numItems: 6,
        numLoaded: 0,
        quotes: quoteData
    };


    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numItems; i++) {

        var quoteObject = ["Inspiring quote goes here.", "Speaker Name"];

        var cardObject = {
            imageURL: './src/placeholder.png',
            quote: quoteObject[0],
            credit: quoteObject[1]
        };

        this.state.cards.push(cardObject);

        //Sleep between requests so Unsplash doesn't block us for overloading it.
        this.sleep(500);
    }

    this.getRandomQuote = this.getRandomQuote.bind(this);
    this.renderCard = this.renderCard.bind(this);
}
```

It's working now - thanks everyone for your assistance! It still needs improving but hopefully I can make it the rest of the way on my own.

Comment: The answers below are good, I would also suggest you don't specificall call renderCard with 0 to 5 but actually use `this.state.cards` with `map` to render the currently available cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors. The following are not all of them, but it is a good start :)
Fix these, post the updated code, post also `quotesData.json` and `App.css`, and we will continue...

### Start by fixing the following:

#### You cannot setState from the constructor.

Add the following after the constructor (and remove the call to `refreshImages` from the constructor).

```
componentDidMount() {  
  this.refreshImages();  
}
```

#### 'this' is not set properly in the following:

```
getRandomQuote();  
renderCard();
```

Add the following inside your constructor:

```
this.getRandomQuote = this.getRandomQuote.bind(this);
this.renderCard = this.renderCard.bind(this);
```

### After your updates, you are almost there :)

The problem that remains is that, although you set the cards value in the right place (`componentDidMount`), setState is asynchronous, so the first time you enter `render()`, cards are still not set.

I replaced the following line:

```
if (this.state.imagesLoaded) {
```

With the following:

```
if (this.state.cards.length === 0) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1 className="App-title">state.images still empty</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );  
} else if (this.state.imagesLoaded) {
```

And I see smart quotes with nice images :)

This is a workaround, of course, you need to decide what to do...
Also, is sleep(500) in refreshImages really needed?

One more advice (not related to the problems you are having): use [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap), it will make your life easier. You need to know bootstrap for that, which is very easy to learn (but don't use bootstrap, use reactstrap).

Good luck with your work :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions - componentDidMount cleared up some confusion for me! I've incorporated your changes and I'm still getting the error - I've updated the OP with links to the new code. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `setState` in the same method multiple times if it's not really necessary (will result in multiple renders). Furthermore `setState` is an async method.

e.g. you should just do this at the end of your method `refreshImages`:

```
this.setState({
  imagesLoaded: false,
  numLoaded: 0,
  cards: result
});
```

And the same for your other methods.

See documentation for further information on `setState`:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Hope this helps.